# Ag-grid replicates CellStyle across the entire column when scroll moves

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I have the following code:

```
const cell = vm.gridOptionsFib.api.setFocusedCell(index, field, null);
const cellFoc = vm.gridOptionsFib.api.getFocusedCell();
const rowNodeCell = vm.gridOptionsFib.api.getRowNode(cellFoc.rowIndex);
const column = cellFoc.column.colDef.field;               
cellFoc.column.colDef.cellStyle = { 'backgroundColor': 'rgba(233, 30, 99, 0.3)' };
vm.errGrid = "mensaje tooltip";
cellFoc.column.colDef.tooltipValueGetter = function() {return vm.errGrid;};
vm.gridOptionsFib.api.refreshCells({force: true, columns: [column], rowNodes: [rowNodeCell]});
vm.gridOptionsFib.api.clearFocusedCell();
```

This works excellent and marks the cell I am specifying, the problem comes when I move the horizontal scroll and when I return to the specified column it paints all the cells when I only specify one.

Does anyone have an idea why it does this or do I need some instruction.

Comment: maybe refreshcells or rowIndex can be a reason on here, did you try use the cellclassrules or cellstyle on the columndefs

Comment: Hello! yes I tried with cellStyle and cellClassRules, the problem is that it is performing the validations from backEnd and marking the cells that are incorrect. I tried adding an extra property to the columnDefs and it was doing the same thing of marking the whole column instead of the cell.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone has the same problem, the solution applied is to set the following properties in the gridOptions.

```
suppressColumnVirtualisation: true,
rowBuffer: 9999,
```

Comment: This is option is not working in the tree structure data